# Get my ad on a site with google ads

Tags: google-ads-api

I have thinked about if this is possible.

My competitors running Google ads on their website. I wish that I run Google Adwords and get my advertising shown there (the competitors shows 728x90 google ads banners). Is this possible? - should I just run keywords on their site is in the meta keywords?

```
<meta name="description" content="Chat, sjov, ballade, tale sammen, ungdom, ungdomsproblemer, brevkasse, kærlighed, flirt, avatar">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adwords has an option called ["Managed Placements"](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99502). You can add your competitor's URL there. Please note that he may block ads linking to your website in his Adsense account.